# SQL insert data from another database base where userid and metaid match

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I have a `user_auth table` in `db1` that has the following columns:
    `user_id | user_name | first_name | last_name`

I have a `user_meta table` in `db2` that has the following columns:
    `umeta_id | user_id | meta_key | meta_value`

`Umeta_id 1` & `2` are the first and last names. How can I select `first_name` and `last_name` from `db1` and insert them into `db2` where `umeta_id=1` or `2` and `db1.user_id=db2=user_id`

Comment: Can you access db1 and db2 ftom the same DB server?

Comment: What do you mean by "Umeta_id 1 & 2"?  Are there two separate fileds: Umeta_id1, Umeta_id2?

Comment: It's a bit confusing you seem to have a key value pair in user_meta but also then go on to say about 1 & 2 being different things. Are you not just using meta_key to specify the first_name?

Comment: Yes db1 and db2 are on the same server. Bsivel you're right that is extremely confusing. 

Daniel you're right as well. After looking at it again I need to match the meta_key "first_name" with the user_id in the user_meta table.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on the specifics but I'll have a go, how about this?

```
INSERT INTO db2.dbo.user_meta(user_id, meta_key, meta_value)
SELECT user_id, 'first_name', first_name FROM db1.dbo.user_auth

INSERT INTO db2.dbo.user_meta(user_id, meta_key, meta_value)
SELECT user_id, 'last_name', last_name FROM db1.dbo.user_auth
```